# how to search array by specifying the index to start search from in php

Tags: php, arrays, search, indexing

how to search array by specifying the index to start search from in php

for example:
Assuming

```
$needle_to_search = 5;
$array_to_search = [6,8,4,9,7,5,9,4,5,9,3,5,4,6,7];
$index_to_start_search_from = 5;
$key = array_search($needle_to_search, $array_to_search, $index_to_start_search_from);
```

is there any function that can implement above pseudo code
so that `$key` will return index: 8

what i mean is that i want to start the search from index 6 so that it returns index 8=> which has the value 5, since value 5 is my aim to search in the array.

Comment: Can you provide the example array with the key you want to start at as it would save the time of the people that are trying to answer your question. Though, maybe [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635) might help.

Comment: values provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do with `array_slice`.

```
$needle_to_search = 5;
$array_to_search = [6,8,4,9,7,5,9,4,5,9,3,5,4,6,7];
$index_to_start_search_from = 6;
```

// output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 9
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 5
    [12] => 4
    [13] => 6
    [14] => 7
)

// return 5
echo array_search($needle_to_search, $array_to_search);

// return 8
echo array_search($needle_to_search, array_slice($array_to_search, $index_to_start_search_from, null, true));
```

Comment: Thank you but not satisfactory

Comment: why @myckhel, then how you are expecting. could you please clarify me

Comment: I hope you understand now

Comment: Thanks alot , that's what i need